# RabbitMQ + kombu: write/read to one-time use queues with random names

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, kombu

I am new to working with message exchange and met problem finding proper manual for the task.

**I need to organize pool of queues so, that:**

1. Producer create some random empty queue and write there all the pack of messages (100 messages usually).
2. Consumer find non-empty and non-locked queue and read from it till
   it's empty and then delete it and look for next one.

So my task is to work with messages as packs, I understand how to produce and consume using same key in one queue, but can't find how to work with the pool of queues.

We can have several producers and consumers run in parallel, but there is no matter which of them send to whom. ***We don't need and ever can't link particular producers with particular consumer.***

**General task:** we have lot of clients to receive push-notifications, we group pushes by some parameters to process later as group, so such group should be in one queue in RabbitMQ to be produced and consumed as a group, but each group is independent from other groups.

**Big thanks to Hannu for the help:** key idea of his easy and robust solution that we can have one persistant queue with known name where producer will write names of created queues and consumer will read these names from there.

**To make his solution more readable and easy work** with in future in my personal task, I have divided publish_data() in producer into two function - one make random queue and write it to control_queue another receive this random_queue and fill it with messages. Similar idea is good for consumer - one function to process queue, another will be called for process message itself.

Comment: Do you have several producer and consumer applications?  And is the "another possible variant" acceptable as well? That is how I would probably do it, or a variant of that.

Comment: Hannu, I updated question with answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks. I posted an answer candidate. It does not shine with its "kombuness" but it works and will at least give an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this but with Pika. I had to clean and kombufy an old code snippet for the examples. It is probably not very kombuish (this is my absolutely first code snippet written using it) but this is how I would solve it. Basically I would set up a control queue with a known name.

Publishers will create a random queue name for a pack of messages, dump N messages to it (in my case numbers 1-42) and then post the queue name to the control queue. A consumer then receives this queue name, binds to it, reads messages until queue is empty and then deletes the queue.

This keeps things relatively simple, as publishers do not need to figure out where they are allowed to publish their groups of data (every queue is new with a random name). Receivers do not need to worry about timeouts or "all done" -messages, as a receiver would receive a queue name only when a group of data has been written to the queue and every message is there waiting.

There is also no need to tinker with locks or signalling or anything else that would complicate things. You can have as many consumers and producers as you want. And of course using exchanges and routing keys there could be different sets of consumers for different tasks etc.

**Publisher**

```
from kombu import Connection
import uuid
from time import sleep
def publish_data(conn):
    random_name= "q" + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "")
    random_queue = conn.SimpleQueue(random_name)
    for i in xrange(0, 42):
        random_queue.put(i)
    random_queue.close()
    return random_name


with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//') as conn:
    control_queue = conn.SimpleQueue('control_queue')
    _a = 0
    while True:
        y_name = publish_data(conn)
        message = y_name
        control_queue.put(message)
        print('Sent: {0}'.format(message))
        _a += 1
        sleep(0.3)
        if _a > 20:
            break

    control_queue.close()
```

**Consumer**

```
from Queue import Empty

from kombu import Connection, Queue


def process_msg(foo):
    print str(foo)
    with Connection("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//") as _conn:
        sub_queue = _conn.SimpleQueue(str(foo))
        while True:
            try:
                _msg = sub_queue.get(block=False)
                print _msg.payload
                _msg.ack()
            except Empty:
                break
        sub_queue.close()
        chan = _conn.channel()
        dq = Queue(name=str(foo), exchange="")
        bdq = dq(chan)
        bdq.delete()


with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//') as conn:
    rec = conn.SimpleQueue('control_queue')
    while True:
        msg = rec.get(block=True)
        entry = msg.payload
        msg.ack()
        process_msg(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I understood your idea and briefly tested it, so far looks nice. I will test it more and accept in a couple of days.

Comment: There are of course many other ways of doing this, but I like this because it does not need any signalling, synchronisation or control structures except the use of control channel. This will have Rabbit do all your scheduling, distributing and messaging for you, and it does it well as it was designed for exactly that.  The only common interface is the control channel. No bidirectional traffic is needed, or communication between peer processes. Everything can and should stay separate, and with message acks rabbit provides you with a fail safe mechanism free of charge, too.

Comment: Yes, this code works, and the main idea of use control_queue for transferring queue names is brilliant, this is the key of the problem I was missing.
To make solution more readable and easy work with in future, I divided publish_data() in producer into two function - one make random queue and write it to control_queue another receive this random_queue and fill it with messages. 
Similar idea is good for consumer - one function to process queue, another will be called for process message itself.

Comment: Of course.  Separating control queue processing and message queue processing would make sense. Might be suitable for threads, too. The above code is just a proof of concept.